# Cannot override 'webkit-any-link'

Tags: html, css, browser

Consider:

```css
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

I can't override this CSS. I tried the post
*[Blue lines under links on my site even though I've disabled all related CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268712/blue-lines-under-links-on-my-site-even-though-ive-disabled-all-related-css)*.
I tried a lot. Still it’s not working. I don't want to modify each and every machine to change the user agent style sheet.

Comment: what you trying to do? because `-webkit-any-link` or `-moz-any-link` are  pseudo classes for CSS4

Comment: Have you tried `a:-webkit-any-link { text-decoration: none !important; }`?

Answer (score 26):

If you are saying that the styling

```css
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

is being set automatically somehow and you want to override it, start by simply setting anchor styling in your CSS:

```css
a, a:link, a:visited, a:focus, a:hover, a:active{
  color:olive;
  text-decoration:none;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

If this doesn't work for some reason, add additional selectors to increase the [specificity of your rule](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), for example,

```css
body a{
   ...
}
```

if this still doesn't work, use the dreaded `!important`:

```
color:olive !important;
```

See this live: https://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/z7mkvbeu/

As suggested by [kca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7556457/kca), this [page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception) has good details about how the `!important` rule works, but why it's preferable to avoid it if possible.

Comment: i tried different solutions like using `!important` but finally solution which worked was add style in html code inside h1 tag!

Comment: @Freddy, adding inline styling would have increased the specificity, check the link I posted if you want to know more about why this worked - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: A more in depth question would be: why do vendor browser push devs to override styles when we have a CSS spec with specificity rules precisely to have control over this...?

Comment: I suggest to add a link to the [!important exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception), which also includes the statement that this is bad practice (people might wonder why not just use `!important` right away).

Answer (score 1):

Try to override it globally by (be aware don't use comma-separated to combine them):

```css
:-webkit-any-link {
}

:-moz-any-link {
}

:any-link {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar situation.

```
<a href="#">
    <i class="icon-home"></i>
</a>
```

Icon underline, did not disappear after

```
a {text-decoration: none;}
```

And as a result, the browser still showed the underscore. Since this error was not there in another browser.
The solution turned out to be very simple: clear the cache and cookies.
It wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: Clearing cache does not help in any of the browsers (latest Chrome, FF, IE) I use.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, weird specificity.

`webkit-any-link` color was overriding my class color, e.g., nav `.nav-item-style{color: ...}` in HTML like:

```html
<body>
  <nav>
     <a class="nav-item" ...
```

The fix for me was related to the above, adding 'a' tags to my CSS reset section, without a color and somehow that fixed it.

```css
a,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:focus,
a:hover,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Interestingly, I then removed the 'a' tag styles to take a screenshot of what I was seeing in inspect/dev tools (MS Edge) and the problem did not return.

Comment: Does "dev-tools" imply [Google Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome)?

Comment: no, I was using Edge. right now I'm thinking that reloading cache may have fixed it also.

Answer (score 0):

The specificity [David has warned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303995/cannot-override-webkit-any-link/37037391#37037391) you about is key to overriding rules, when all code is right. Without seeing your code, I cannot know if this applies to you, but to other coders to land here: please double check your rule. It is *very* likely that you have a typo on your rule, causing it not to be recognized and the default to be applied.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Maybe, I don't have the rep to comment on another's answers, anyway. But it is an answer, i had the same problem (that's how I found this question) and after research and fiddling, found that the exact error can be achieved by a typo, disabling his rule, and he was getting the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can override it by setting the property

```css
:any-link { color: green }
:any-link:active { color: orange }
```