# Can't remove Link hover underline

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

been struggling trying to get rid of the underline of all Links globally in my NextJS project.

Been trying both css (by importing globals.css file into _app.tsx) and via ChakraUI.

The only way I can get it working is by using:
`<Link style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>`  but I do not want to use it on 100+ links :)

Any ideas?

**_app.tsx**

```
import "../styles/globals.scss";
...

const theme = extendTheme({
  global: {
    a: {
      _hover: {
        textDecoration: "none",
      },
    },
  },
  breakpoints,
  fonts: {
    heading: "Poppins",
    body: "Poppins",
  },

  textStyles: {
    h1: {
      // you can also use responsive styles
      fontSize: ["48px", "72px"],
      fontWeight: "bold",
      lineHeight: "110%",
      letterSpacing: "-2%",
    },
    h2: {
      fontSize: ["36px", "48px"],
      fontWeight: "semibold",
      lineHeight: "110%",
      letterSpacing: "-1%",
    },
    h3: {
      fontSize: ["36px", "48px"],
      fontWeight: "semibold",
      lineHeight: "110%",
      letterSpacing: "-1%",
    },
    h4: {
      fontSize: ["14px", "18x"],
      fontWeight: "semibold",
      lineHeight: "110%",
      letterSpacing: "-1%",
      textTransform: "uppercase",
    },
  },
  components: { Input: { baseStyle: { _focus: { boxShadow: "none" } } } },
});

function MyApp({ session, Component, pageProps, country, flag }) {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          <Component {...pageProps} country={country} flag={flag} />
        </SessionProvider>
        <ScrollButton />
      </ChakraProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
export default MyApp;
```

**globals.scss:**

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover -webkit-any-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot override webkit-any-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303995/cannot-override-webkit-any-link)

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Create a custom `Link` component that wraps the Next.js `Link` and styles it as you want, then use that instead across your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Toothfairy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238995/toothfairy), this is probably a late reply, but you need to tell next to allow styledComponents.
I had a similar issue. It kept causing hydration errors, on reading the docs, I found the cause. I then followed a git repo, and checked the next.config.js file. To fix,

in next.config.js, add:

```
compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },
```

source: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

for the repo: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-styled-components/next.config.js

As for my theme, I used:

```
components: {
  Link: {
    baseStyle: {
      '&:hover': { textDecoration: 'none' },
    },
  },
};
```

[next.js](/questions/tagged/next.js) [hydration-error](/questions/tagged/hydration-error) [chakra-styled-components](/questions/tagged/chakra-styled-components) [chakra-ui](/questions/tagged/chakra-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

```
                     import React, { Component } from 'react';
                     import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
                     import styled from 'styled-components';


                    const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
                         text-decoration: none;

                    &:focus, &:hover, &:visited, &:link, &:active {
                    text-decoration: none;
                      }
            `;

                    export default (props) => <StyledLink {...props} />;
```

Comment: in _app.tsx? ...

Comment: yes. did it work let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To override the Chakra Link hover effect, you can customize your theme and set the Link baseStyle.

```js
export const theme = extendTheme({
    Link: {
      baseStyle: {
        // normal styling
        textDecoration: "none",
        // hover styling goes here
        _hover: {
          textDecoration: "none",
        },
      },
});
```

You can also do this as a variant so only some Links remove the hover.  eg. if you have extra fancy css styling on hover for your nav links.